# Searching in a text file in a nested loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a 4 columns tab separated text file. Also I have a list of values which need to be iterated through and searched in the text file to get the value of one of the columns:

Here's my code (Python 2.7):

```
def populate_data():
  file = open('file.txt', 'r')

  values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
  secondary_values = ['second_value1', 'second_value2', 'second_value3']
  os = 'iOS'

  i = 0
  outputs = []
  while i < len(values):

    value = values[i]
    secondary_value = secondary_values[i]

    output = lookup(file, os, value, secondary_value)
    if output != None:
      outputs.append(output)
    i += 1

def lookup(file, input_os, input_value, input_secondary_value):
  for line in file:
    columns = line.strip().split('\t')
    if len(columns) != 4:
      continue
    else:
      value = columns[0]
      secondary_value = columns[1]
      os = columns[2]
      output = columns[3]

      if input_os == os and input_value == value and input_secondary_value == secondary_value:
        return output
```

The search basically should work as this SQL statement:

```
SELECT output FROM data_set WHERE os='os' AND value='value' and secondary_value='secondary_value'
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the lookup method works in the while look and also maintains a for loop and obviously the parent while loop doesn't wait for the inner loop to finish and return the value before continue. This results in a problem that despite of the fact of the match the data is not returned. If this was JavaScript I would do that with Promises, but not sure how to achieve it in Python.

Any clues how this could be solved?

Comment: ``populate_data`` already builds a list of results, why doesn't ``lookup`` do so as well? Are you looking for a generator perhaps? Are you familiar with ``yield``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search in a TXT file containing tab-separated values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622616/search-in-a-txt-file-containing-tab-separated-values-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately no, @GiftZwergrapper. The problem is that there's an inner loop to read the file rows and the outer while loop is not going to wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do here was to read the file and insert all of the rows into a dict like so:

```
dc = dict()
dc[value+secondary_value+os] = output
```

Then accessing the values in the main while loop.